# Upserting a list of SObjects is creating duplicates

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I have an external Id field called `Unique_Identifier__c` which is a concatenation of two fields on this Custom SObject `Recipient`. This field is created/populated at before insert.

I want to allow the user to update records and I do not want to create duplicates in the system. I am upserting a list of these Custom SObjects at before insert after looping through all Recipients who have a match between their Unique Identifier and what is in the map.

When I go to upsert it is

1. updating records that match with the Unique Identifier and
2. creating duplicates

Why is my upsert creating duplicates if I am giving the External Id to match Recipients on? Should I be doing this in before insert? When replacing upsert with update it is also creating duplicates.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's not much we can do to help you. If you're doing it right, no duplicates should be created.

Comment: is it possible for to you copy and paste your code here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to discard the duplicate values for external field, we need select the **"Unique"** option which will not allow duplicate values to be stored in system by Treat "ABC" and "abc" as duplicate values (case insensitive).

[image]